# How to integrate Payment Gateway in React Native with any merchant's UPI?

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, upi

I have multiple stores and customers in my application and each store has it's own UPI.

```
Ex: Store1's UPI = 'store1@bankxyz"

    Store2's UPI = 'store2@bankabc'
```

Customers can select any store and pay any amount using UPI/credit card/debit card/net banking.
How can I implement this functionality using existing payment gateways like Paytm/Razorpay so that amount is transferred to the UPI of the store that is selected?

Answer (score 0):

With Paytm payment gateway, you can get this done by mapping each store as a separate mid. Also you can integrate the All-in-one SDK solution of Paytm payment gateway for your app, that is supported on react native. You can visit the developer portal of paytm payment gateway.